# Output each file processing to separated dirs in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a virus RNA in 35 files, and I need to process it to reach information.

I working on velvet. It's program working in conda env. It has two steps:

**1** velveth - Got file, create roadmap and output it to new dir

```
velveth newDir 29 --create_binary -short -fastq -filename
```

**2** velvetg - create contigs.txt

```
velvetg /$newDir #where newDir is just a path to dir creating in first steps.
```

I can't write in bash. I tried to found some tutorials in internet, and I wrote something like this:

```
END=32

list = (file1
        file2
        file3
        ...
        file35)

dir = "assembl"
for i in {1..$END}

do
newDir = ${dir}${i}
velveth newDir 29 --create_binary -short -fastq -${list[i]}
velvetg /$newDir
echo '$i + ${list[i]} >> logs.txt
done
```

As U can see, I need to have each output in separated dir, and in `echo '$i + ${list[i]} >> logs.txt` I tried to put output to know which file went to which folder.

So each file shoud be in next assembl : assembl1, assembl2 etc.

But it dosen't work. I got many errors depends of modification - premission denied (I have premissions), dir not found etc.

So RESUME:
I need to run step one for all file from list and each output put in separeted dir (one dir = output from one file)

Then I need to use second steps on that dirs. So step two shoud run 35 times, once for each dir.

EDIT: After yours adive I modify to it, and I hope it's work well. I mean I have no sure that for example first file go to first dir etc. But it works.

```
dir="assembl"
for i in {1..32}
do
newDir=${dir}${i}
velveth $newDir 29 -create_binary -short -fastq ${list[i]}
velvetg \$newDir
echo "$i + ${list[i]}" >> logs.txt
done
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$files`? And `$list` is unused. What are you actually trying to do, create strings `file1` to `file32` to use as input to a command?

Comment: Ouh, too many modification. I edited post. It's not files now but list.

Comment: Just off the cuff. There should be no `;` after the `for` and on the `veleth` line, `newDir` needs to be `$newDir`

Comment: OK, i deleted it. But it's appear another error. It's looks like something wrong with 'newDir = ${dir}${i}', Do I properly adding 'i' to assembl?

Comment: Put your script in shellcheck. You can have no spaces around = in assignments, (for example, `dir = assembl` should be `dir=assembl`)

Comment: @Quasímodo is correct.  Also, your for loop needs to be `for i in ${list[@]};`  $END has nothing to do with it. Sorry about my "forget the semi-colon" comment before.

Comment: OK it's running. I will see what's about result in few minute. But I have a question. I just run it, and it's isntat create 35 dirs. Shoudn't it create one dir, process first step, then precess second step, and then create second dir etc. ?

Coz now I have 35 created dirs and it's processing first file.

Comment: @jiveturkey what about my ${dir}${i} then? It will be still adding integer to my dirname?

Comment: Again, @Quasímodo is correct.  I ran the following `#!/bin/bash
END=32

list=(file1 file2 file3 file35)

dir="assembl"
for i in ${list[@]};

do
newDir=${dir}${i}
echo "velveth $newDir 29 --create_binary -short -fastq -${list[i]}"
echo "velvetg /$newDir"
echo '$i + ${list[i]} >> logs.txt'
done` through https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler just fine.  Had to `echo` since I don't have your applications. It's ugly so...copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks for all answer. I update my code based on your suggestion. And I think all works besides `echo '$i + ${list[i]} >> logs.txt` it's generating in log.txt just literraly: i + file[i]. How can I improve it?

Comment: @jiveturkey I can't apply  ` for i in ${list[@]};` coz then I got error in `'$i + ${list[i]}`
I need to generate log: i (fileNumber) +  file name. In example where I use @ in list I got fileName and error coz I tried to do list[filename]

Comment: `echo` has a bunch of shortfalls. It should be easy enough I just don't use it enough.  Try `printf "%d%s" $i "${list[i]}" >> "$LOGFILE"`  Or something like that

Comment: Did this work out for you?

Comment: @jiveturkey I something else, all code run. And it's running now, but result will be in few hours. Will see :) Thank U for help